# Can't use ⌃⌘Space for Evernote Helper as shortcut is already in use

Tags: macos, keyboard, evernote, shortcut

I love Evernote and I used to Evernote helper with the shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.

I have since reinstalled Mavericks and now can't use this shortcut any more.

Just changed Special Characters shortcut to <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. (it was <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>), but I still can't use this shortcut for Evernote helper.

Evernote only says:

> The key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> can't be used!
>   The key combination "Command + Control + Space" can't be used because it's already used by a system-wide keyboard shortcut. (If you really want to use this key combination, most shortcuts can be changed in the Keyboard & Mouse Panel in System Preferences)

…but I've already changed the Special Characters shortcut.

Comment: so it sounds like you changed special characters away from using the cmd ctrl space shortcut, but did you set evernote helper to use that shortcut (in the same place)?

Comment: Yes. right. but I can't understand what place is. Helppppp...

Comment: I tried as well to change the shortcut for the emoji icons.  Although the new shortcut does work Evernote still won't let me use ⌘⌃space.   I wonder if they have it hard coded so that you can't use ⌘⌃space keyboard shortcut combination.  i was able to assign ⌘⌃space to another app shortcut key with no problem, for example Spotlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Spotlight** and disable the **Show Spotlight window** option.

[image]

Comment: thx for your help. But I'm telling about com ctrl space.

Comment: @HyunHee Apologies, the post was edited for kbd tags and I didn't notice it changed the key